# git log grep inside the content change

Tags: git

I have a repo with 100K+ commits. There are very few commits (≈500) might have a word PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT text in the commit message.

```
git commit -m "PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT: This is project boat's first commit";
```

Each commits made for more than one file (Lines added, lines removed, filed removed, files added, etc...).

As part of any commit (not specific to PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT), there is a specific keyword (say BOAT_TODO) might have been added/removed from any files.

```
git diff ./file1

+BOAT_TODO


git diff ./file2

-BOAT_TODO
```

I would like to do

- Filter commits which have PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT in its message
- Among those on each file, the number of times the word BOAT_TODO added & removed.

Comment: you want them in one command or is it ok to have separate commands?

Comment: Having it in multiple commands is file. Anyway, I am going to use the output in Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following command:

```
git log --grep=PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT --format=%H | xargs -L1 sh -c 'git diff $0^ $0 | COMMIT="$0" perl -ne '\''if (/^[-+]{3} [ab]\/(.*)/) { printf "%s %s %d %d\n", $ENV{COMMIT}, $n, $x{"-"}, $x{"+"} if $n && $n ne $1; $n=$1;} $x{$1}++ if /^([-+]).*BOAT_TODO/; END{ printf "%s %s %d %d\n", $ENV{COMMIT}, $n, $x{"-"}, $x{"+"}; }'\'''
```

Essentially, that iterates over each commit with PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT in the commit message, prints the hash, then invokes a `git diff` command and filters the output to find lines introducing a file name or containing “BOAT_TOOD” that are either added or removed, and prints the output in the form `<commit> <filename> <removals> <additions>`.

That is a single command, which is what you asked for, although it's not particularly pretty.  I've formatted it as a shell script below in case that's more appealing.  You can also use a different scripting language if you prefer something other than Perl, but Perl is available on all systems where Git is, so I picked it in case you're using Windows.  You can adjust it in case you're using spaces in filenames or things like that.

Finally, if you want to avoid a bunch of (although not all) lines with no additions or removals, you can add the argument `-G BOAT_TODO`, which will restrict Git to printing only those commits which contain “BOAT_TODO”.  Otherwise, it will print data for all commits that contain “PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT”, regardless of whether the commit contains any instances of “BOAT_TODO”.

If you were looking for something simple and elegant, I apologize; Git doesn't provide a simple and elegant way to do what you want, and scripting is definitely the Git way to achieve your goals here.

```
#!/bin/sh

git log --grep=PROJECT_BOAT_COMMIT --format=%H | \
    xargs -L1 sh -c '
    git diff $0^ $0 | \
    COMMIT="$0" perl -n -e '\''if (/^[-+]{3} [ab]\/(.*)/) {
        printf "%s %s %d %d\n", $ENV{COMMIT}, $n, $x{"-"}, $x{"+"} if $n && $n ne $1;
        $n=$1;
    }
    $x{$1}++ if /^([-+]).*BOAT_TODO/;
    END {
        printf "%s %s %d %d\n", $ENV{COMMIT}, $n, $x{"-"}, $x{"+"};
    }
'\'''
```

Comment: How to search a keyword within the text content of a commit (not commit message) and show in context?

Comment: That's a different question and should be asked separately.